# Why do Ubuntu AMIs only have 8gig on root

Tags: amazon-ec2, storage, aws

I've created an EC2 instance from an Ubuntu AMI but the instance storage is split, with 8gig on the root and the rest mounted at /mnt

Why is this?
How do I get it all mounted on the root?

Comment: does this help: http://www.donmeltz.com/resizing-my-ubuntu-sever-aws-boot-disk/ ?

Comment: No this is in reference to EBS

Answer (score 1):

This is just the way AWS provisions ephemeral storage based instances. It is not unique to the Ubuntu AMIs

Answer (score 1):

The default root partition for Ubuntu in AWS is 8Gb.

You can change this to whatever size you need. Currently, AWS support 16 TB (EBS) Volumes

Default AWS documentation: [How to run-instances](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/run-instances.html)

Using command line directly:

```
--block-device-mapping "[{\"DeviceName\":\"/dev/sda1\", \"Ebs\":{\"VolumeSize\":100} } ]"
```

This will create your root volume 100Gb.

You can see more tips and tricks here:
[How to use –block-device-mappings to manage instance volumes with AWS CLI](http://blog.xi-group.com/2014/11/small-tip-how-to-use-block-device-mappings-to-manage-instance-volumes-with-aws-cli/)

Regards.